# How do I make a playsound command follow the player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm in Minecraft 1.12.2 (because of mods I use), and would like to have game music in the background. So, I want the sound made by a `playsound` command to follow the player.

I use this command:

`/tp @e[tag=sound] (which makes sound) @p /execute @e[tag=sound] ~ ~ ~ playsound music.game voice @a ~ ~ ~ 0.3 (to change the volume of sound) 1 0.1`

..but it won't run.

What can I do to make this work?

Note that I don't want to change the `0.3 1 0.1` values.

Answer (score 0):

/playsound minecraft:music.game voice @a[tag=sound] ~ ~ ~ 0.3 1 0.1

Does this work for you?

Also I changed @e to @a so it would only target players, unless that's what you want.

Comment: I want to the sound following me. like minecart sound

Comment: Playing it @a the player should work